# Flutter for iOS device

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-ios

Can I use Android Studio in macOS to run flutter app(for debug and hot reload) on my personal iPhone after I have registered my device using Apple ID on Xcode? Or will I need to use Xcode itself if I want to run my app on a physical iPhone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

q : Can I use Android Studio in macOS to run flutter app(for debug and hot reload) on my personal iPhone after I have registered my device using Apple ID on Xcode?

a : You can use

q :Or will I need to use Xcode itself if I want to run my app on a physical iPhone.

a : You can run it directly from android studio

[install and run flutter on mac](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos)